# application goes unresponsive and need to be restarted each time after protractor's angular e2e was runned

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have a python application mapped in localhost:PORT. I have some angular e2e test and when I run it with protructor (very basic ones, just login to the system), my application going to be unresponsive and I need to reload it to make work again. But If I implement the same actions like in tests, but by hands, all seems working fine and application works stable.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: it's hard to do that. Because my tests is actually very basic (like from examples), but application instead is enterpise one, so impossible to put it there somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is somehow connected with webdriver, it took the connection or something like that. I found that after test execution I will stop webdriver, all stuff continue to work.